# Installing pyOpenSSL on Bluemix

Tags: ssl, flask, pyopenssl, ibm-cloud

I have troubles installing pyOpenSSL on bluemix. I have a self-signed certificate I want to use with my flask app. When adding pyopenssl to requirements.txt and pushing onto cloud, staging fails.

Here is dump from logs --recent: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M5fAJddC

Looks like Bluemix's pip complains about libffi-dev but I have no idea how to solve it. Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out myself. After going through pip repositories I've noticed there is a package called *cffi*. Adding cffi to requirements.txt before pyOpenSSL solved the problem.

Just a little warning, after restarting app I got *out of memory* error. Turns out, these two libraries eat ~38.9MB RAM (72.1 compared to 34.2 in last push) when used in flask.

Unfortunately, now I am getting *502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.* when opening the page. But that is quite different problem I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which buildpack you are using but it doesn't look like it includes libffi dependency. I found [this](https://github.com/kennethjiang/heroku-buildpack-python-libffi) python buildpack that includes libffi. You might want to try it as a replacement for the buildpack you are currently using.

Comment: I'm using heroku/heroku-buildpack-python. Will try this, thank you!